# How to add image in dropdown in angularjs

Tags: image, angularjs, combobox, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-options

I am working on dropdown with image in angularjs, i tried many solution but havent get any success.

My combo data is coming in json format with three elements id , image and value.
These dropdown numbers are also dynamic as per number of rows are there in model.

Please share the solution for that.

Thanks you.

Comment: can you put your code here?

Comment: Select2 supports custom item markup and there's and AngularJS adapter, you might want to try them.

Comment: <select name="webmenu" ng-click="xxxxChange(xxxx)" id="webmenu" ng-model="xxxx.xxxxCombo">
    <option  ng-repeat="obj in xxxxComboData" value="{{obj.id}}" data-image="assets/images/icon2.png"><img src="assets/images/icon2.png">{{obj.value}}</option>
     </select>

Comment: <select ng-model="choice">
    <option ng-repeat="item in itemsList" data-image="{{item.url}}">{{item.label}}</option>
<select>

Comment: @Archana Thanks for solution, but image is not visible when i tried your solution.

Comment: @Himanshu Can you share the sample in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this it will work out,

```
   <select ng-model="choice">
        <option ng-repeat="item in itemsList" data-image="{{item.url}}">{{item.label}}</option>
    <select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <select ng-model="image_chosen">
     <option ng-repeat="data in list" data-image="{{data.url}}" value="{{data.id}}">{{data.value}}</option>
     <option value="">Choose a option</option>
   </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Checkout a example at **[angularjs select option with custom format value](http://angularjsaz.blogspot.com/2015/11/angularjs-select-option-with-image.html)**

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Write like this in option tag

ng-repeat="obj in xxxxComboData" data-image="{{obj.image}}"